# I need to check if the series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2+(-1)^n}}$$

Hey, I need to know if the series above is convergent, absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

I tried using all the tests we learned, but I failed

Comment: What tests were those? What made them fail?

Comment: @JohnDoe $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2+(-1)^n}}$

Comment: @DougM oh yeah haha, not sure how I misread that

Answer (score 2):

Break it up into two series, where $n$ is odd and where $n$ is even. The *even* series converges absolutely by the $p$-test. The *odd* series will diverge by comparing with the harmonic series. Altogether, your series *diverges*.

Comment: What is wrong with saying: The absolute value of the terms converge to $0$, and the sum is alternating, so the sum converge?

Comment: The terms of the sequence are not decreasing. This is a great example showing that decreasing really matters in the Leibniz Alternating Series Test.

Comment: @MeMyselfI If you're trying to apply Leibniz Theorem (or Test): you need the absolute value terms converge **monotonically** to zero.